# Error in build.xml while executing

Tags: java, shell, ant, build

I am getting following error when I am running my build.xml.

```
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess: make.exe -C src/win32 clean error=193
```

This is the code snippet where error is being thrown.

```
<target name="clean-win32">
    <exec dir="." executable="make.exe">  // error in this line
        <arg line="-C src/win32 clean" /> 
    </exec>
</target>
```

I am not able to debug the issue. Any help is greatly valued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was make.exe was not present in my cygwin/bin folder. The issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused most likely because ant cannot find the executable `make.exe`.

If you run it from an IDE, the default folder when running this is most likely the project root. You specify this to be the current folder when executing `make.exe` (with `dir="."`).

Check if `make.exe` is in your project root, and if not, change the `dir` attribute of the `<exec>` tag to the folder where it is located.

Comment: I am not able to find this file make.exe in my project folder and in the root also (where it is intended to find). Is it a possibility that make.exe is not getting created?Because of that only you can clean it .

Comment: The ant XML part you posted is supposed to execute `make.exe`, not create it. Your problem is you want to execute something that doesn't exist.